# Prove the following set of functions is equicontinuous

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact metric space.

a. Prove that every continuous function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous.

b.

Let $T,S:X\rightarrow X$ be isometries.

Let $f_1 \in C(X, \mathbb{R})$.

Prove that the sequence $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, where:

$f_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\Big(f_n(T(x))+f_n(S(x))\Big) \quad\forall x\in X, n\in \mathbb{N}$.

is bounded and equicontinuous.

I've been able to do (a), and also prove that it is bounded but I'm stuck on the equicontinuity. I only have a vague intuition that I should somehow try to bound it using $f_1$ but I cannot develop this (e.g., for equicontinuity at $x_0$, the triangle inequality:
$$|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)| \leq |f_n(x) - f_1(x)| + |f_1(x)-f_1(x_0)| + |f_1(x_0)-f_n(x_0)|$$
doesn't seem to lead anywhere). I'm aware I didn't use the recursive relation nor the fact the $T$ and $S$ are isometries in this part, but I'm not sure how.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $M_n=\sup \{|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|: d(x,y)\leq \delta\}$. Using the fact that $T$ and $S$ are isometries conclude that $M_{n+1} \leq M_n$ for each $n$. This implies $M_n \leq M_1$. Use uniform continuity of $f_1$ to finish the proof.